# Javascript using prototype how can I set the value of "this" for a number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, set, prototype

So if we can get past the "should you?" question ... does anyone know how to set the value of an integer in prototype?

```js
Number.prototype.add = function(num){
  var newVal = this.valueOf() + num;
  this.valueOf(newVal);
  return newVal;
}

var rad = 4001.23;
document.write(rad.add(10) + '<br/>' + rad);
```

You'll notice rad.add(10) returns the number contained in the variable "rad" plus 10, but I would really like to change the value of rad from within the prototype add function (something I know this.valueOf(newVal) does not accomplish).

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Comment: Observations: `this` cannot be assigned. `valueOf` doesn't mutate `this`. Numbers are immutable.

Comment: you need to make a different Number, like Integer, Real, or Float, and use the prototype of that new constructor to do what you want, which is possible on an object but not a primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you cant, Numbers, Booleans and Strings are immutable

Answer (score 1):

```js
Number.prototype.add = function(num){
  var newVal = this.valueOf() + num;
  this.valueOf(newVal);
  return newVal;
}

var rad = new Number(4001.23);
document.write(rad.add(10) + '<br/>' + rad);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has both number primitives and `Number` objects. Number primitives are immutable (like all primitives in JavaScript). The numeric value of a `Number` object is also immutable. So your `add` method can only return the updated value. You can create your own number-like object, of course, with a mutable value.

[Details about number immutability and your own number object in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878395/157247) *(didn't realize that question was a duplicate when answering it)*.