# Javascript Number Prototype Set Value Directly

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype

I try to set a number directly from a prototype method. 
Usually, a new value is returned.

**this** of a number object, is also an object. But I guess not a reference. (?)

I have this:

```
Number.prototype.bitSet = function(bit) {
    return this | (1<<bit);
};
```

But want this:

```
Number.prototype.bitSet = function(bit) {
        this.value = this | (1<<bit);
    };
```

this.value is a pseudo property. Becuase this sould be a reference of the number and without that, you'll overwrite it. But the question is: Is this really a reference to the source number?  Is it possible to do that? Assign the value directly to the number who called this method?

```
var num = 0; 
num.bitSet(9);
console.log(num); // num = 512
```

Btw. chrome console prints [[PrimitiveValue]] for the number.

Comment: Just noticed [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130463/javascript-using-prototype-how-can-i-set-the-value-of-this-for-a-number?rq=1) under "Related." This is indeed a duplicate of that question. (I prefer my answer here, but then, well, I would. :-) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR - You can't do that, your initial version of `bitSet` is how you need to define it. You'll need to save its return value when you use it, e.g., `x = x.bitSet(2)`. You can create your own mutable number object, though, if you like. (More on that below.)

Just for clarity (you probably know this): JavaScript has both number *primitives* and `Number` *objects*. Normally, you're dealing with primitives. The reason `Number.prototype` works is that a temporary object is created using the primitive's value when a method is called on it. Unless something explicitly saves the object, though, it's as though we were just dealing with primitives.

Numbers are not mutable in JavaScript.<sup>1</sup> So your `bitSet` method cannot change the numeric value of what it's called on; instead, it has to return a new number with the changes made (e.g., your original version).

Note that even if you could change a `Number` object's value, you're almost never dealing with a number object in code outside functions you've assigned to `Number.prototype`. For instance:

```js
Number.prototype.bitSet = function(bit) {
    return this | (1<<bit);
};
var x = 32;
x = x.bitSet(2);
console.log(x); // 36
console.log(typeof x); // "number", not "object"
var o = new Number(36);
console.log(typeof o); // "object"
```

In the above, when `x = x.bitSet(2);` is executed, the number *primitive* is converted to a temporary `Number` object, your `bitSet` method is called, and then the result is whatever your `bitSet` method returns; unless `bitSet` does something to store `this` somewhere, the temporary object is then thrown away. (That's the *theory*; in fact, your JavaScript engine may well optimize away the object entirely, if it can determine that the code in your function only uses the number as though it were a primitive number.)

So suppose in my code above, we did something to change the state of the `Number` object in that `x.bitSet(2)` line. Since that object is *temporary* and not stored anywhere (unless we store it; it's not in `x`, `x` contains a primitive number), whatever we stored on the object would be lost. We can even prove that:

```js
Number.prototype.test = function() {
  this.foo = Math.random();
  console.log("this.foo", this.foo); // some number
};
var x = 42;
x.test();
console.log(typeof x);       // "number", not "object"
console.log("x.foo", x.foo); // undefined
```

`this` was definitely an object, we added a property to it and used that property. But `x` still had the primitive.

You could have your *own* mutable number type, though:

```js
function MyNumber(value) {
    this.value = typeof value === "number" ? value : 0;
}
MyNumber.prototype.bitSet = function(bit) {
    this.value = this.value | (1 << bit);
};
MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.value;
};
MyNumber.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.value.toString();
};

// Usage:
var m = new MyNumber(42);
m.bitSet(2);
console.log(String(m)); // "46"
var n = m + 5;
console.log(n);         // 51
```

The `valueOf` function is called any time the JavaScript engine needs to convert your number object to a number. `toString` is called when the JavaScript engine needs to convert your number object to a string.

Or in ES2015:

```js
class MyNumber {
    constructor(value) {
      this.value = typeof value === "number" ? value : 0;
    }
    bitSet(bit) {
      this.value = this.value | (1 << bit);
    }
    valueOf() {
      return this.value;
    }
    toString() {
      return this.value.toString();
    }
}

// Usage:
var m = new MyNumber(42);
m.bitSet(2);
console.log(String(m)); // "46"
var n = m + 5;
console.log(n); // 51
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *"Numbers are not mutable in JavaScript"* Technically, that's not true. *Primitive* numbers are not mutable, but `Number` objects are — but their underlying numeric value (what the spec calls its `[[NumberData]]`) cannot be changed. (`Number` objects can have other properties with state that can be changed, just not their numeric value.) So "Numbers are not mutable in JavaScript" is a reasonable shorthand statement, if not perfectly correct.