# JS: Subclass built-in Number class

Tags: javascript, class, subclass, subclassing

I have a problem with subclassing built-in `Number` class. I can change properties but I want to change original number which class holds e.g. I want to call a setter method and it will recreate instance with new constructor parameters.

Now my code looks like:

```js
class Color extends Number {
    // ...
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
    get r() {
        return (this.valueOf() & 0xFF0000) >> 0x10;
    }
    set r(r) {
        // here I want to set my instance to
        new Color((this.valueOf() & 0x00FFFF) + (r << 0x10));
    }
    // ...
}
```

The reason I want to subclass `Number` is to minimize RAM usage when I'll have thousands of instances. (I mean, `Number` needs only 4 bytes to hold it in Memory as far as I know).
Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot change the underlying data of `Number` objects

Comment: @adiga thank you for reply, any suggestion how to go around this limitations by design?

Comment: Please check the duplicates: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878395/3082296) explains it in detail and suggests some alternatives

Comment: "*I mean, Number needs only 4 bytes to hold it in Memory as far as I know*" - no. A raw double might, but a `new Number` instance (or a `new Color`) is an object and will take more than that.

Comment: If you really have thousands of colors, I would suggest working with an `Uint8Array`.

Comment: @Bergi for now, I got about 120mb usage for 1920x1080 matrix of instances. Any suggestions how to implement all of my calculation functions around Uint8Array?
I see only way with getting color, build class with it way, make calculations get raw value and then commit changes...

Comment: Either don't use a `class` and instance objects at all, but only static functions that operate directly on the typed array (given an index, instead of an instance), or construct temporary, short-lived objects if you need OOP for anything and store the updated values immediately.